# Angular CLI: Can't change base in index.html

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have **Angular 2** app generated by **Angular CLI** tool.

When I change **base** to any value in **index.html**:

```
<base href="test">
```

and build the app (ng build) the resulted **index.html** has:

```
<base href="/">
```

So my question is: **How can I change base in index.html**?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The base URL is used to resolve relative URLs in the page. Making the base URL relative as well does not make any sense. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: When building the electron app the base has to by changed to "./" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--base-href` option on `ng build`. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build