# Deploying Angular app in a different folder than root folder

Tags: angular, nginx

New to Angular.  App works fine if deployed in `nginx`  `/var/www/mydomain.com/html`.  But I want to deploy it in `/var/www/mydomain.com/html/myapp` folder.  I setup `nginx available sites` to this folder and `index.html` works fine.  But relative paths in Angular app (e.g., images/mypic.png) being attempted to be retrieved from `/var/www/mydomain.com/html/images` folder (hence 404 error code) instead of `/var/www/mydomain.com/html/myapp/images` folder.    How do I set a url prefix `/myapp` globally in Angular so all relative paths have this prefix.  I have seen some answers here but they require changes in the component code.  Isn't there a way to made this setting at deployment time so the same `dist` can be deployed in any path?

Comment: You can configure the path in angular.json or angular-cli.json file. Give your path for key "outputPath". eg: "outputPath": "myapp"

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43830250/1009922).

Comment: Yes that seems like the only choice.  I was hoping I could make that change in the dist after build.  Thanks.

Comment: If you use Webpack, [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-href-webpack-plugin) appears to work.

Comment: Did you try setting proper baseRef in index.html or angular.json? It has to be set properly in order for assets to load.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

###On `angular.json` > `build` > `options` configuration add this line with target sub directory

```js
        "baseHref" : "/v2/",
```

**like this **

```js
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "baseHref" : "/v2/",
```

Comment: Option `deployUrl` is now deprecated.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71695674/what-is-best-way-to-go-about-replacing-deployurl-in-angular-json-for-v13)

Answer (score 7):

Use the following command, here /myapp/ is the relative path to the root site.

```
ng build --prod --base-href /myapp/
```

Comment: Great - make sure to include the leading and lagging '/' around your subfolder otherwise it may lead to weird routing behaviours