# ng build --base-href serverip/dir : Assets (css, js, img) points to server ip

Tags: angular

Consider localhost 127.0.0.1

ng build command is executed on a directory called "mainproj/subproject"

```
ng build --base-href 127.0.0.1/mainproj/subproject
```

The build is created in this specific directory.
The assets points to 127.0.0.1

How do I (or) where do I make changes so that assets refer to the directory where the build is created as root and not the server i,e in this case localhost(127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
"baseHref" : "http://127.0.0.1/mainproj/subproject",
"deployUrl": "http://127.0.0.1/mainproj/subproject"
```

in angular.json under "build : options" works.
I am still a little sceptical of it.

The solution link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50889024/deploying-angular-app-in-a-different-folder-than-root-folder/#answer-54030262).