# How to add deploy url for single spa in angular 14

Tags: angular, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I am trying to migrate my angular micro app to latest angular version built on top of single spa but now in angular 14 deployUrl has been deprecated. How can I achieve the same functionality ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is best way to go about replacing 'deployUrl' in angular.json for v13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71695674/what-is-best-way-to-go-about-replacing-deployurl-in-angular-json-for-v13)

Answer (score 0):

You can add deployUrl property under build:options in angular.json file of your app.

Comment: This solution is not working, I'm still getting the deprecation warning.

Comment: @JSONDerulo can you post the screenshot of that error or can you provide your source code link if that code is already on GitHub?

Comment: I created a new project with `ng new` and did what you suggested, after that the warning appears.