# Angular, replacement for deployUrl in ASP.NET MVC project, with areas, for lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular

We use ASP.NET MVC with areas so a typical url may look like this

https://local:6789/_SomeIISFolder/Area/Controller/Index

we have deployUrl set to

"deployUrl": "Areas/Area/Views/AngularCommon/Ang/",

which you may notice isn't a url, it's a disk path, i.e. "Areas" and "Views" aren't path of the url, they are part of the disk path

The deployUrl is only needed because otherwise lazy loading files doesn't work, instead of a path like https://localhost:1234/_IISBit/AreaName/..../somelazyloadfile_ts.js the url becomes https://localhost:1234/somelazyloadfile_ts.js, which is annoying because without lazy loading it just works

The official documentation talks about replacing this with APP_BASE_HREF
https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-deploy-url

but I can't see how to do this. We can't change the base href, and changing the APP_BASE_HREF doesn't seem to help

One thing that does work is something that seems like a real hack, in main.ts

```
declare var __webpack_public_path__: string;
__webpack_public_path__ = 'Areas/TheArea/Views/SomeFolder/Ang/';
```

Comment: This issue has been discussed at length in [this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22113) and there is also an [so] question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71913980/1260204. Do those answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I was aware of those before I posted. Lazy loading is the key part here, and the github discussion seemed to end with "it's not a problem"

Comment: I have to say, I also find this to be a weird problem. It loads the angular files from the right place, then looks elsewhere for the lazy loaded ones, even though Angular outputs all the files to the same place

Comment: We use the `__webpack_public_path__` and the value we use comes from `environment.ts` . We made the change ever since `deployUrl` stopped working for us (after the upgrade to v13 I believe) and have had no issues so far.