# Hybrid angularjs/angular app broken due to angular 13+ removal of deployURL

Tags: angular, angularjs, webpack

**UPDATED 7/6/2023 as I believe I have determined the issue is due to the hybrid nature of my application and not just upgrading angular as I previously assumed.**

I have a hybrid angular/angularjs app that currently builds all the client files into a `/client/` directory.
All calls outside of that directory are handled by my back end.  My current configuration uses `deployUrl='/client/'` to prefix all asset requests appropriately for that directory.

I am upgrading angular, and so `deployUrl` is now deprecated/removed, and I am trying to figure out how to make this continue to work.

I have tried setting my angular.json `baseHref='/client/'`, like recommended here:
[What is best way to go about replacing 'deployUrl' in angular.json for v13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71695674/what-is-best-way-to-go-about-replacing-deployurl-in-angular-json-for-v13)

and that works fine for the assets, but it breaks the angularjs portion of the app.  In particular, when angularjs $location attempts to parse the initial url, it gives an error.  Ie, Assume the initial url is `https:/example.com/home`, when ajs tries to parse it, it throws this error:

```
Error: [$location:ipthprfx] Invalid url "https://example.com/home", missing path prefix "https://example.com/client/".
```

Which links to [this error in the angular docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/docs/error/$location/ipthprfx?p0=https:%2F%2Fjabba.bulbapp.com%2Fb%2Fbootstrap&p1=https:%2F%2Fjabba.bulbapp.com%2Fbulb-ngclient%2F).

Apparently angularjs doesn't like the baseHref, which wasn't previously a problem as deployUrl didn't require a baseHref.  However, now that I can't use it, I can't seem to do the workaround of setting baseHref either, since angularjs doesn't work well with it.

Any ideas how I can set up/build my app so that both the angular and angularjs portions work?  (Yes, I would love to get rid of all the angularjs code, and we are doing so slowly, but we still have a lot of legacy code in ajs).

Comment: Have you tried like it's suggested by the link from the error? To set the "<base>" in `index.html`? It should have the same value you provide in deployUrl/baseHref. It's a native HTML thing for fetching assets

Comment: @Sergey, yes, I tried that.  If <base> is anything besides "/", then I get the $location:ipthprfx error when it tries to parse the current browser address/location.

Comment: What if you build with "/" and update the value after the build is done?

Comment: @Sergey, angularjs appears to actually grab the value from the dom while it is running, so if I change it after the build, I still get the same runtime error.  I tried to do the opposite, building with a value, and updating it to "/" after the build, but there are lots of references that break in that case.

Comment: I think the error actually points the error correctly. You are on one URL path, but use different URL path in base. That might be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving the problem.  I am posting this just in case anyone else is interested, though I can't necessarily recommend this solution because $browser is technically a private angularjs object, so it isn't designed to be modified/tweaked, and isn't even documented.  However, the solution worked for us, and we are okay with the risk of ajs changing something under the covers and breaking things, particularly because not that many changes are happening to ajs nowadays.

I basically overrode the default $browser.baseHref() method to return '/' rather than the value specified via  in the index.html.  That way, I could still specify a baseHref during the angular build, so all the client assets/resources/scripts are found correctly, but the angularjs $location behavior and ajs ui router is not confused by it.

I added this to the app config portion of my angularjs bootstrap:

```
$provide.decorator('$browser', ['$delegate', ($delegate) => {

  $delegate.baseHref = function replacementBaseHref() {
    return '/';
  };

  return $delegate;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share an example, how you call your backend?
We serve an angular application with the baseHref option and call the backend like

```
this.http.get(`/v1/ressource`);
```

that works fine. It might be the leading `/` that is important.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I have updated my question to clarify the error that the <base> href is causing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for you too, but we have a similar setup (hybrid application) and what we do is:

1. Setup up the `APP_BASE_HREF` provider in a module (we're declaring the `AppRoutingModule` for this) and include it in the `imports` of `AppModule`:

```
// app-routing.module.ts
import {APP_BASE_HREF, ...} from '@angular/common';
// ...
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
            // enableTracing: !environment.production,
        })
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'},
        {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: ... your strategy ...}
    ],
    declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}

// app.module.ts
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        AppRoutingModule,
        // ...
    ],
    // ...
})
export class AppModule {/*...*/}
```

2. On `index.html` set your path with:  `<base href="/client/">`
3. On the npm config, in `package.json`, we set the option `--serve-path` for the `serve` and `e2e` commands. Example `ng serve --serve-path '/client/' --port 4300`. But you can also set this option on the configuration(s) for `serve` inside `angular.json`:

```
// angular.json
// projects -> your-project -> architect -> serve -> options {
"servePath": "/client/"
```

Also, worth mentioning, in our cypress configuration we have:

```
// cypress.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
  env: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4300/client/'   // with or without the '#' depending  on your location strategy.
  }
});
```

**Just for curiousity**
We have a newer project (not on hybrid anymore) and the settings above work on a pure Angular 14 app too. But out of curiosity, I tried out and changed `APP_BASE_HREF` to `/client/` to see what would happen.

1. In our hybrid application, it duplicates the `/client/` when changing into newer routes. The older (angularJS) seem to work.
2. In our newer app (non hybrid), it doesn't seem to affect anything, so apparently `/` and `/client/` would work (but I just tried this locally and not on production though, so I'm not 100% sure).