# I want to serve angular application from jar with custom context: localhost:9001/web-app

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, jar

I created a single jar file with both server and frontend (spring + angular12). Everything is working fine, but i want to create a custom context for the web app (localhost:9001/web-app). I tried to create a different folder structure inside the static folder and i also tried to add a basePath in angular.json.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I haven't misunderstood, you can achieve this by doing this :

In **angular.json** > **build** > **options**, add this two lines

```
"baseHref" : "/web-app/",
"deployUrl" : "/web-app/",
```

as they advised in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50889024/deploying-angular-app-in-a-different-folder-than-root-folder)